# Please help choosing a router

Tags: router

Please, could anyone give some advice on what router would be sufficient for this task:

bgp4 - 2 uplinks,

traffic: 600-800 mbit/s

What router model would suit me? I would prefer a cisco model since I'm more familiar with them, but any model would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We don't do buying questions such as this, not only is there not enough information but it's subjective and of no use for the wider community which is one of our key objectives.

Comment: Whatever it is, It's gonna be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

A call to Cisco pre-sales support or their online chat would answer this easily.